HTML checkbox input with (click) event listener stops checkbox tick from showing when clicked
I have recenty taken on an Angular17 project and have been going through code left to me by previous developers. One issue that has come up has to do with checkbox inputs in a table.
Whenever any checkbox is clicked, it is expected to call a function. It does so successfully, however the checkboxes don't get 'ticked'.
Here is the HTML I am working with which generates the checkboxes (some variable names have been changed):
<tbody *ngFor="let header of headerArray; let headerIndex = index;">
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let row of tsidRows; let rowIndex = index;">
            <!-- If all variables have a value -->
            <span *ngIf="header.headVarA && header.headVarB && row.rowVarA">
                <!-- Normal Checkbox -->
                <div *ngIf="!(!this.repositoryArray.includes(header.headVarA) && row.rowVarB)">
                    <input #prodCheckbox type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" 
(click)="createProductAllocation($event, header.headVarA.substring(0,6).trim(), header.headVarB.substring(0, 8).trim(), row.rowVarA, row.rowVarB, rowIndex)">
                </div>

                <!-- Error Checkbox -->
                <div *ngIf="!this.repositoryArray.includes(header.headVarA) && row.rowVarB">
                    <input #prodCheckbox type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" disabled>
                </div>
            </span>
            <!-- If any variables are missing - Error Checkbox -->
            <span *ngIf="!header.headVarA || !header.headVarB || !row.rowVarA">
                <div>
                    <input #prodCheckbox type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" disabled>
                </div>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

The *ngIf statements are probably irrelevant, as the checkboxes are still being generated normally. The class form-check-input is a Bootstrap class.
The function createProductAllocation(...) is also not relevant, as calling any function, including:
testFunction() {
    console.log("Hello World");
}

stops the checkbox from ticking. The checkbox.checked attribute returns true after clicking, but since the checkbox is not ticked, I cannot 'untick' it to return it to false. The checked attribute also does not get added directly into the element when inspecting the HTML in developer tools.
I also have this function in the .ts file that unchecks all the checkboxes when an update is made earlier in the component, but after adding in a console.log, I determined that this is never called when a checkbox is clicked.
@ViewChildren("prodCheckbox") pcheckboxes: QueryList<ElementRef>;
uncheckAll() {
  this.pcheckboxes.forEach((element) => {
    element.nativeElement.checked = false;
  });
}

I won't lie, I asked ChatGPT to see if I could get a quick solution; none of the suggestions there worked. Below is what I've tried so far:

Having the (click) event call a different function, which then calls my actual function.
Changing (click) to (change)
Changing ChangeDetectionStrategy from OnPush to Default
Manually forcing event.target.checked to true
Using changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
Delegating the (click) event to a parent element
Using Angular Renderer2 to force the checked property to 'checked'
Making an entire Angular checkbox component to handle the events

After trying everything listed above, the function still called successfully, but the checkboxes still didn't tick. Removing the (click) event listener allows the checkbox to tick/untick like normal, but obviously doesn't call the function anymore.
All I'm wanting, is to have the checkbox element call the function when it's state changes, while having it tick/untick, which I assume is normal behaviour?
I've been trying to fix this for about 3 days now, and I thought this would have been a simple fix. Any help is really appreciated.

see that if your function "createProductAllocation" change() the array "tsidRows", Angular should "repaint" the whole table. ()Change is create a new array, not change one element of a property of onw element, e.g. some like: myarray=[...myarray] change the array, myarray[index].value="newValue" not change the array. One solution can be add a new property "checked" to your elements and bind -using, e.g. [ngModel] the value of the checkbox.

I'm using (click) or (change) to detect when the state of the checkbox is updated. The function that is called does not make any changes to the tsidRows array. This doesn't matter anyway since having a simple function with only a console.log in it gives me the same issue.

I can reproduce your problem. BTW try use trackBy in yours *ngFor, but I feel that the problem is in other place. Has you any variable in your .ts named prodCheckbox? (if true rename this variable)

that template reference variable "#prodCheckbox" should probably be unique.  Try removing those from the error checkboxes.  (but you might also check for any "preventDefault()" calls on the event.)

@Eliseo I do not have a variable called prodCheckbox unfortunately.

@browsermator Even if I remove it from the error checkboxes, it won't be unique if multiple normal checkboxes are generated, yeah? There are also no "preventDefault()" calls on the event.
I have updated the post to include a function that uses the #prodCheckbox template reference variable to uncheck all of the checkboxes. Although this sounds like the function that would be causing the issue, it is not called when a checkbox is clicked.

I just want to answer this now as I have a fix thanks to a suggestion from @Eliseo
They suggested using trackBy in my *ngFor loops, to which I implemented it like this:
<tbody *ngFor="let header of headerArray; let headerIndex = index; trackBy: trackByHeaderIndex">
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let row of tsidRows; let rowIndex = index; trackBy: trackByRowIndex">
            <!-- If all variables have a value -->
            <span *ngIf="header.headVarA && header.headVarB && row.rowVarA">
                <!-- Normal Checkbox -->
                <div *ngIf="!(!this.repositoryArray.includes(header.headVarA) && row.rowVarB)">
                    <input #prodCheckbox type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" 
(click)="createProductAllocation($event, header.headVarA.substring(0,6).trim(), header.headVarB.substring(0, 8).trim(), row.rowVarA, row.rowVarB, rowIndex)">
                </div>

                <!-- Error Checkbox -->
                <div *ngIf="!this.repositoryArray.includes(header.headVarA) && row.rowVarB">
                    <input #prodCheckbox type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" disabled>
                </div>
            </span>
            <!-- If any variables are missing - Error Checkbox -->
            <span *ngIf="!header.headVarA || !header.headVarB || !row.rowVarA">
                <div>
                    <input #prodCheckbox type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" disabled>
                </div>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

trackByHeaderIndex(index: number, item: any) {
  return index;
}

trackByRowIndex(index: number, item: any) {
  return index;
}

This worked and now the function gets called, and the checkboxes are ticked/unticked as normal.
